# Logitech mouse driver alternative for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, software-rec, drivers, mouse

I've had my Logitech MX Revolution for several years now, and I still like it a lot. However, when I first installed the software that came with it, Logitech's drivers required Application Enhancer (APE, which I don't want), and they kind of sucked anyway. They were glitchy and not particularly user-friendly or Mac-like.

[image: Logitech MX Revolution]

I looked around for third-party drivers, and pretty much the best thing I found was [SteerMouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/), which isn't any more Mac-like than Logitech's, and is semi-poorly translated from Japanese, but is more flexible and doesn't require APE. However, it's not free.

In the time since then, I've just been using Mac OS X's default mouse drivers, but that doesn't allow me to use the nice features of the mouse like the forward/back buttons, thumb wheel, horizontal scrolling speed adjustment, auto-activation of the free-spinning scroll wheel, etc. So, now I've brought the question here: **what good, free Logitech-compatible mouse drivers/software exist for Mac OS X?**

My requirements:

- Forward/back button settings (it's *really* nice to adjust these just by setting keyboard shortcut equivalents, like Logitech's software allowed)
- Horizontal scrolling speed adjustment
- *Application-specific* settings (I **loved** being able to have the forward/back buttons do relevant things in each application)
- Nothing too hacky, glitchy, or ugly!
- *Free!* (otherwise I'll just continue being cheap and using the built-in drivers!)

Things that would be nice, but I'll live without:

- Awareness of the mouse's free-spinning scroll capabilities, and auto-activation
- Support for the thumb wheel/button
- Support for the top "search" button

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've not found a lot of quality free replacement mouse drivers for macOS/Mac OS X.

There are two non-free options that I've evaluated, and either is good for me. Note that I don't have a Logitech mouse on my MacBook, I have an [Evoluent Vertical Mouse](http://www.evoluent.com/vm3.html).

- [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/)
- [SteerMouse](http://www.plentycom.jp/en/steermouse)

Comment: Have used steer mouse for a few years now

Answer (score 1):

I was saddened that the  Logitech Control Center (LCC) doesn't support my M-100 corded optical mouse. It does support my V450 cordless optical mouse and works quite well with it. but I'm back to using the M100 and all the features work perfectly without Logitech Control Center.

What I did was downloaded a trial version of USB Overdrive 3.0.1, installed it, configured the wheel button to open my Dashboard and it worked perfectly. I then considered that the driver was going to cost me more than the mouse so I uninstalled USB Overdrive and rebooted my system.

Guess what??? The scroll wheel button worked exactly as it did with USB-Overdrive installed. It's been several days and reboots have not affected the functions of any of the features of the M100.

Answer (score 0):

I recently bought a VX Nano and I didn't need to install any drivers. The back/forward buttons work as well as the tilt to scroll feature. But the web search button was mapped to autoscroll.

To deal with the search button I installed [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com) which should almost definitely work for everything except the second scroll wheel and the auto activation of the hyper-scroll wheel. Unfortunately USB Overdrive isn't free but if you are willing to pay for it, or don't mind closing a dialog box every time you log in, USB Overdrive should work fie for you.