# Setting back and forward as mouse buttons on a mac

Tags: mac, mouse

I'm a recent Mac convert, and reusing my good old Logitech MX500 mouse. One thing that I really miss is having Back and Forward set to the side buttons (buttons 4 and 5 I believe). Is there any way to do this? I'd like to have it work at an OS level (in Finder), but I'd settle for just having Safari work too.

I tried USB Overdrive, but that ended up screwing other things up too. I do have Exposé, Dashboard, and Spaces mapped to other buttons on the mouse and don't want to lose those either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the logitech control center installed in the sys preferences?
[logitech control center download](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/drivers/logitechcontrolcenter.html)

That should let you map all the buttons you want.

Comment: I was really hoping to not have to install any logitech software :=/ I've had bad experiences...

Comment: I agree with the non-Logitech driver idea. See my previous question about it: http://superuser.com/questions/7652/logitech-mouse-driver-alternative-for-mac-os-x

Comment: This ended up being the best way. Though it looks like Logitech's Mac software isn't as awful as its Windows stuff.